# terraform: tfsec not able to read EKS cluster encryption configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, tfsec

I have an EKS cluster resource to which the team has added [encryption_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster#encryption_config), We are adding a dynamic block probably to add multiple configurations. Now when I am trying to run tfsec ( version 1.28.0 ) on my code I get a [Cluster does not have secret encryption enabled.](https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.28.0/checks/aws/eks/encrypt-secrets/)

Here is the dynamic block

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
...

dynamic "encryption_config" {
    for_each = toset(var.cluster_encryption_config)

    content {
      provider {
        key_arn = encryption_config.value["provider_key_arn"]
      }
      resources = encryption_config.value["resources"]
    }
  }

}
```

definition inside variables.tf

```
variable "cluster_encryption_config" {
  description = "Configuration block with encryption configuration for the cluster. See examples/secrets_encryption/main.tf for example format"
  type = list(object({
    provider_key_arn = string
    resources        = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `cluster_encryption_config` used?

Comment: We are using this module https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v17.24.0/variables.tf#L380 I think this is the one ( not sure )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you write `cluster_encryption_config` is set to empty list `[]`. Therefore, `encryption_config` block does not run, and there is no encryption configured. You have to setup `cluster_encryption_config` to something with valid values (not an empty list).

Comment: I see, so whenever default value is empty in a variable, and tfvars file or command line is not used to input variable, that particular block or variable wont be set for the resources, is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes, because `for_each = toset(var.cluster_encryption_config)` will have nothing to iterate over if you provide empty list.

Comment: thank you for the answer and teaching this concept :D